# Removing server(s) from google load balancer for testing software patch

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine

How to remove server(s) from google load balancer for testing software patch

I know to hack the server to make it unhealth is one way to do it.
But it like a hack.

Is there proper UI panel where we i can click exclude from load balencer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click "Remove From Group" from the Instance Group page, it will leave the server running but not send traffic to it.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-unmanaged-instances#removing_instances_from_a_group